# How can I stop bolts from loosening over time?

Tags: bolts

Here is a picture of what I intend to use:

[image]

I believe (and could be wrong about this) that over time as the structure is moved, the nut that was fastened to hold the structure together will gradually loosen. Is there way to make the nut so tight and fixed that it will never become loose automatically, but only when the user needs to open it?

Comment: Clarify please; do you plan on the fastener being easily removed regularly with hand tools?   Or is it acceptable to make it permanent and require destructive removal ?

Comment: If we knew what the structure was, and was made of, we may well come up with better fixings than nuts/bolts.

Comment: Note, the OP's use case is [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14382). Also, it's highly unlikely that anything more than a pair of washers and a good, firm _snug_ on the wrenches is necessary to keep this particular assembly "tight enough". Unless you're moving the desk on a regular basis, that's all you're going to need. This won't just fall apart on its own - there are no inherent vibrations as there might be for bolts on a car.

Comment: OK, the bolt will keep together two panels of chipwood, where one is put on top of the other and bolted togeher. Then the panels are connect vertically in a desk so their face is facing wall. When can bolts loose overtime, I am not sure.

Comment: I hope Handy Mandy reads this thread...

Comment: @quantum231 I've noted several follow-up questions on several of the answers. While I fully understand that you're a beginner and you need to learn (learning is _GOOD_), you're _seriously_ overthinking this! Have any of the bolts on the original desk come loose while the desk was just simply sitting there? If you're moving it all the time, then yeah, it _could_ be a problem, but for 99.999% of us, a desk, once assembled, just sits there and desks. Bolts don't just come loose on their own on stationary objects. Moving objects like cars, dishwashers, etc. are a different story.

Comment: I wish I had a carpentar friend so I could ask everything. I am a senior electronic engineer and end up having to critically think about everything. Anyway, I am satisfied with the information I have. This topic is closed now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

instead of (or with) a regular washer:

[image]

you can use these tension ones:

[image] [image]

then there is also one with a rubber side:

[image]

as for a nut already suggested:

[image]

or two regular ones and lock the first one with the second:

[image]

or hardlock nuts:

[image]

of course the best (one time) securing is to weld bolt and nut:

[image]

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer but everyone has provided valuable input. I hope page will help people in the future.

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way is to replace the nut with a Nylanut AKA [Nyloc nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyloc_nut):
[image]
<sup>By Original uploader was Btarski at en.wikipedia. - Originally from en.wikipedia; description page is/was here., CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5047606</sup>

These provide resistance such that it will not (easily) unscrew unless you use a wrench/socket to remove it.

You could also use a lock washer between the nut and the washer.

Comment: Or Threadlocker, or... **Red threadlocker** (not great for wooden things joined - the blowtorch needed to convince it to let go might scorch the wood a bit..

Comment: Good answer, but use a tool kind of imply's a special tool, instead of a little bit more force with common wrenches/ratchets.

Comment: @crip659 I agree and made an edit.

Comment: Another option is to use locking nuts - have two nuts - tighten once as normal and then tighten the second while holding the first.  This is the old way of doing it :-)

Comment: Remember nylock nuts are supposed to be single use only.  Subsequent reuse has a lower resistance so they come off easier.  Enough reuse, and the grip degrades down to that of a plain nut.

Comment: @Criggie even winding them down a long thread on assembly reduces the hold, at least on small sizes.

Comment: @RohitGupta jam/lock nuts like this are still often the best solution for a solid hold without preventing future adjustment/disassembly. That's how a lot of bike bearings work, for example. You can buy thin "half nuts" to use as the locknut if space is limited.

Comment: Based on the [OP's use case](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14382), Nylocs will be sufficient, as would thread locker or a simple lock washer.

Comment: Rohit has given a very good and simple trick. For Nylocs, the basic idea is that it will exist at the end of the bolt and prevent it from loosing. The Nyloc will live at the end of the bolt such that the bolt might have some freedom to move horizontally in the hole that it lives in, but will never fully open and come off. Is that correct?

Answer (score 30):

**Thread Lock Adhesive**

You can use a thread locking compound, such as this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - good first answer.  You might want to call out the different 
"strengths" of thread locker, like "hand tool" vs "heat release"

Comment: Note that thread locker doesn't work on all metals. There are primers available that are basically copper oxide suspended in a solvent that remedy this.  Thread locker also takes (generally) 24 hours to cure at room temperature.  It's a good idea to spend 5 min reading the manufacturer's instructions before using it.

Comment: I'm confused! I always though _blue_ Locktite could be loosened with tools, while the _red_ required heat, yet this package seems to indicate that the red can be removed with "hand tools".

Comment: @FreeMan, welcome to the world of Loctite, where the (standard) blue threadlocker comes in a red bottle and the (high strength) red threadlocker comes in a blue bottle. {facepalm}

Comment: ummm... What. The. Heck??? (Funny story: I've got a bit of thread locker in my toolbox. It came with something I had to assemble and it's a blue liquid in a _white_ bottle. May or may not be Loctite™ brand...)

Comment: My purple loctite came in a red bottle as well.  Only the name (low strength) is in purple.  I almost grabbed the wrong one the last time I used it and put high strength on a faucet's retainer bolt.

Comment: I did not know something like this existed. I am truly fascinated by the answers.

Answer (score 25):

You can also find bolts with a locking nylon patch applied, like these from Nylok:
[image]

These are useful if the bolt is going into a blind threaded hole.

**Added The Following**

As I said in a comment below, these are considered superior to even locking adhesives in that chance of an assembler applying the wrong amount of locking compound is eliminated.

For our hi-rel applications, there's a specified process that's followed when using these, and similar fasteners, which include the following:

1. The bolt is torqued to the proper setting, using a calibrated torque wrench.  There are always two operators involved, one to do the tightening and another to witness that the proper torque was used.
2. Depending on the application, we may apply a dab of structural adhesive to the head of the bolt to further ensure that it won't back out.

Comment: Wasn't aware of those; thanks for the tip!

Comment: Nylok nuts have been around for a very long time - are these new in comparison?

Comment: @Tim - I don't know when those nylon patch fasteners first showed up.  We've been using them for at least 20 years or longer in the aerospace industry.

Comment: Depends so much on the usage...for safety critical usage the nylon is probably better, but for normal home use the adhesive is way more practical. The adhesive is more flexible--you don't have to plan ahead, just use it with whatever you've already got. Especially helpful if you tend to modify or repair existing things that come with hardware. And the actual hardware is reusable, if you bolt everything together and then need to open it up again you're only out a tiny bit of adhesive.

Comment: Wait, this is a nylok _bolt_ instead of nut? Who knew? This is awesome info, thanks!

Comment: @user3067860 - Agreed that for most home use & DIY applications, the adhesive is more practical.  It is way, way cheaper and easier to obtain than the bolts-with-nylon-patches.

Comment: I never knew such a thing even existed.

Comment: I ran across this type of screw when I visited Costco because my eyeglasses screw was too loose and fell out.  They replaced the screw with a screw which had "loctite" pre-applied to it, like the kind mentioned here.

Answer (score 19):

**Lock Nut / Double Nutting**

If there's enough thread exposed through the joint, then you can fit two nuts.  The first nut is tightened to the required torque for your application, and the second nut is then tightened against the first nut, to a higher torque value.

Traditionally the locknut has been thinner than the main nut, but it is possible to just use two of the same nut.

Example - the locknut may have a larger diameter than the original nut, or it may be the same.
[image]

There is some debate about whether the thin locknut should be on first (as pictured) or the correct way where the main nut takes the load and the thinner lock nut goes on last.

Comment: This site recommends the thin nut coming first, as in the picture  https://www.boltscience.com/pages/twonuts.htm

Comment: @BobbyJ yeah there's three schools of thought, and valid points for all of them.   And if one's better than another, its a very small difference.  If your application depends on that difference, then the fastener is under-specced so upsize the biolts.

Comment: Those are typically called "jam nuts" IME.

Comment: you mean a pinch nut!

Comment: @turbo There's probably as many different names for this as there are for a pinch-bar.  It's good to have them so search engines can find the words.

Comment: I see, use two nuts that have different depth. Most interesting,

Comment: @quantum231 they don't need to be different thicknesses

Answer (score 17):

To round out the smorgasbord a bit:

Drill a hole through the nut and bolt when tight, insert a cotter pin.

Or drill a hole only through the bolt and use a castellated nut. Actually two holes at right angles allows finer adjustments (1/12 of a turn rather than 1/6th of a turn to line up one of the holes with the slots in the castle-nut)

Or use safety wire after drilling the hole. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_wire

Comment: This works only when there's enough room to get a drill plus bit in close enough to get the hole something like parallel to the object/s being bolted together.

Comment: Safety wiring nuts used to be standard practice in the aerospace industry.  For the most part, that has been replaced with the nylon (or some other substance) locking patch I showed.  These are considered superior to even locking adhesives in that chance of applying the wrong amount of locking compound is eliminated.

Comment: When I worked one summer as a machinist's helper building heavy mechanical cranes for unloading container ships, we did this. Sometimes we would have the nut welded in place instead. It depended on the specs.

Comment: As it happens, today I was attending a criminal prosecution involving a split pin in a castellated nut on a heavy mechanical crane. Something about the pin not being correctly placed and the resulting accident....

Answer (score 9):

**Flange washer**

This solution requires modification to the bolt, in the form of a channel or slot running up one side.

Then a washer with a tab/flat is slid on before the nut, something like this:

[image]

Once assembled and torqued down, the washer is deformed around at least one side of the nut, by using leverage often from a large flathead screwdriver/crowbar and hammer.

This mechanism is common on car wheel bearings.  Here's a photo from an old landrover. In this example, the washer is sandwiched between two nuts and one segment of the washer has been folded back (away from camera) and another sector is about to be folded forward around the visible front nut.

[image]

Comment: Had never heard of this method - very interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Armand yeah its more for older cars  Mine's a 1973 and the tech was old then.  The washer has to be unfolded to get clearance to undo the nuts, and you could get 2, maybe 3 uses before you're re-rebending metal.  Like nylock nuts, they have a usage cycle or duty count before needing replacement.

Comment: Land Rover Defender?

Comment: Wheel bearings I've worked with had a hole in the spindle and a special nut that was used along with a cotter pin to prevent the bolts from backing out, after it had been torqued down correctly to pre-load the bearings.

Comment: Yup, this is a technique used on more than a few axle nuts, even on newer cars. My VW has a different technique, though: 105 ft/lbs then turn an additional 180°. Stretches the bolt, locks the threads, makes the bolt a 1-time use.

Comment: What exactly can cause bolt to become loose overtime, isn't using something like lockwasher mentioned in answer from QTX enough?

Comment: @quantum231 vibrations (that's the main culprit of bolt loosening) as a byproduct of high RPM. because even "balanced" wheels from a car are just balanced to be "good enough" and not "totally perfect". and even if they would be, then even the smallest rock/pebble can unbalance them and introduce a shockwave of vibrations

Comment: @quantum231 Heat-cycling comes into it too.  Bearings can get hot, and it can be a nasty dirty wet environment.  Plus the forces on a wheel can be enormous, able to override the resistance of a simple system.

Answer (score 9):

Lockwashers like these can be useful in some applications.[image: lockwashers]

Comment: These would be "crinkle washers" to me - other areas will likely have different names.

Comment: You might choose to include split washers and nordlock washers here too, as a retention system under the nut.

Comment: @Criggie - they are star / lock washers to me. Crinkle washers are different, they are literally a very thin flat washer that is crinkled to provide some force when a nut is fastened down on-top, rather than cutting into the surface, like the ones pictured.

Comment: IME, these don't really work, and people tend to over tighten them so they break/fail.

Comment: Does such washers exist for bolts or just small screws? I have seen these type of washers when I was passing by in shop once upon a time, I did wonder what they could be used for.

Comment: @quantum I have a box of assorted star washers, something like M3-M10 (1/8"--3/8").  They're not great, but might be of some help here

Answer (score 7):

Torque the bolt properly.

This preloads the bolt up to some percentage of the breaking load. Under normal use the clamping preload should be *greater* than the dynamic load the bolt sees.

As a consequence of the clamping force being larger than the preload, it will not deform elastically during use, and then nut will not work loose under most conditions.

Comment: Bang on. I'll just add that if the torque setting isn't known for the assembly, then hand-tighten and then use a (torque-)wrench to turn the nut tighter through 90 degrees. This suppresses fatigue-inducing dynamic loads.

Comment: Or you can look up standard values for the bolt you're using. For instance a M8 10.9 zinc plated? 29 Nm. This is a good enough value if nothing is specified.

Comment: yes, certainly this is the most useful answer, i.e pre-empt the loosening of the bolt.

Comment: @vidarlo the OP is bolting together veneered chipboard.  You'd need big washers to spread the load and avoid crushing the veneer

Comment: @ChrisH That's not mentioned in the question. A comment by someone else claims this. As the *question* stands this (and other answers) are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 6):

Another, way more permanent plan is to have the bolt about one thread's worth protruding out of the nut. It may well involve cutting said bolt. Then peen the extra thread over, and the two will never work apart.

If the structure needs to be moved frequently then perhaps a different fixing would do a better job. Pop rivets, welding, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Lockwasher, locking nut as shown above, threadlocker blue (the removable kind)   (choose all three)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155603)

Comment: @gnicko Suggesting 3 ways to solve the issue seems like an answer to me; could you clarify?

Comment: @Armand probably cos its short and lacking in detail, and was posted after a couple of other longer answers covering similar points.

Comment: This seems to be the only *answer* mentioning liquid threadlocker, which in my limited experience is by far the most common locking technique used in auto repair.

Comment: This has the beginnings of a good answer with the threadlock suggestion, but as written it's just a series of brief comments on other answers that came before it.

Comment: @gnicko: Agreed it's not a very *good* answer, especially not mentioning what "threadlocker blue" is.  But it is an answer.  And it was better than nothing before other answers with more detail were posted, since "threadlocker blue" and the others are searchable terms.  It's low enough quality that it didn't deter people from mentioning the same things in their own answers.  Unless this stack is very strict about not answering in comments, though, this is the kind of thing that I'd have posted as a comment.  But posted as an answer, I'd say it is an answer, just not worth an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the application,  you can tack weld the nut to the bolt.  Of course this weakens the nut and bolt,  and you'll need a torch or grinder if you ever want to remove it, but I have seen this technique successfully used many a time.

Comment: I've seen this used to secure remote farm gates, to keep trespassing 4WD drivers out of private land and prevent them lifting a gate off the hinges.  A small portable and self-container welder is invaluable on the farm.

Answer (score 4):

Aircraft used safety wire through the nut/bolt for critical applications. ( May have changed in the many years since I saw them.)

Comment: Probably too hardcore

Comment: Goodness yes, I remember doing this as an apprentice.

Comment: Not only aircraft. It's used in industry in general where positive locking is required. It also makes inspection *very* easy, which has a benefit in some industries. If wire is undamaged, bolt is OK.

Comment: But you have to check that the wire is running the right way - to tighten, not to loosen. Don't ask how I know that.

Comment: Also safety wire requires a fixed point to tie the other end to, often another bolt if there's one close enough.  These are definitely still in use in modern industrial/military installations, but the place they're installed generally has to be designed to use them.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to do is to ensure that, in the final assembly, there is no rotational degree of freedom around the axis of the bolt.

For example, I have a number of cooking pans where a single bolt holds the handle to the pan. They all repeatedly come loose and require re-tightening, because the handle can rotate slightly back and forth around the axis of the bolt. But the same can happen in arrays of multiple bolts, e.g. corners of a rectangle where sides are independent pieces, where the positions of the bolts aren't held rigidly relative to one another, allowing them all to rotate back and forth. No matter what you've done to try to prevent loosening, bolts that act as pivot points will always loosen.

To solve this, you need to have enough bolts, in the right places, to rigidly constrain the whole assembly against this. At that point, you can think about other measures to eliminate loosening from vibrations and other smaller-order effects.

Comment: Pans are also subject to heat-cycling which will back out threaded fasteners over time no matter what.   The best fix is having the cooking base and handle cast from the same metal at the same time then adding a heat-resistant covering to the handle.

Comment: @Criggie: I'm skeptical of that claim, in the absence of rotational motion. I don't experience that with properly torqued threads in 3D printer hotend. But even if it does happen, that's one of the smaller-order effects I was talking about mitigating with other measures. The dominant problem is the rotational degree of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

### Linseed Oil

If you are working on odd-jobs and have an average garage at your disposal, linseed oil congeals to a rubber consistency (See info about [polymerization of linseed oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linseed_oil)) .

[image]

Comment: This is the old-school way of thread locking.  Bicycle wheels use "spoke prep" which was originally linseed oil on initial assembly, allowing smooth tightening of spoke nipples while truing the wheel, which cured after some time and resisted future drift/movement without completely eliminating it.